# improper integral - claim of convergences

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Claim: Let $f:[a,b) \to R $ be a non-negative and continuous function.

Suppose $\int_{a}^{b} e \ ^{f(t)} dt  $ converge , than  $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) \ ^ 7dt$ converge too.

I think this claim is true.

When i tried to prove it I showed that $lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x \ ^ 7}{e \ ^ x}  = 0$ than i wanted to say that this implies that $lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x) \ ^ 7}{e \ ^ {f(x)}}  = 0$ , and than to finish the proof by comparison test.  but this is true only if $lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty $ which is not necessarily true.

How could I continue from here or is there another way to prove this claim ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we examine Taylor series $$e^{f(t)}=1+\frac{f(t)}{1!}+\frac{f^2(t)}{2!}+... \ge \frac{f^7(t)}{7!} $$

So by comparison test, we know the following converges. $$\int_a^b\frac{f^7(t)}{7!}dt$$

Comment: Just to make sure, isn't there need for explanation for that you put $ x= f(t) $ in the Taylor series of  $e \ ^ x $ ? @user115350

Comment: There is a flaw in my answer. I will check that.

Comment: OK, clean up the answer. There is no need to explain the replacement $x=f(t)$ because it is obvious.

Comment: Alright, agree with you, thank you.